# Document creation using Google APIs in Python throws error

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-api-python-client

In the following approach, I tried to create a document and insert data into it:

```py
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
    from google.oauth2 import service_account
    
    SERVICE_FILENAME = 'C:/Users/xyz/Test/service_account.json'  # set path to service account filename
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_FILENAME,
                                                                        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
                                                                                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents']
                                                                        )
    
    drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    docs = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    
    
    def fetch_folder_id():
        page_token = None
        response = drive.files().list(q="mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
                                      spaces='drive',
                                      fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                      pageToken=page_token).execute()
        for file in response.get('files', []):
            # Process change
            print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
            if file.get('name') == "Document_API":
                folder_id = file.get('id')
                return folder_id
                break
            page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
            if page_token is None:
                break
    
    
    def create_Doc(folder_id):
        file_metadata = {
            'name': 'Test.docx',
            'parents': [folder_id]
        }
        file = drive.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    fields='id').execute()
        print('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
        file_id = file.get('id')
        return file_id
    
    
    def grant_permissions(file_id):
        try:
            permission = {
                "role": "writer",
                "type": "user",
                'emailAddress': 'xyz@gmail.com'
            }
            return drive.permissions().create(fileId=file_id, body=permission).execute()
        except Exception as e:
            print('An error occurred:', e)
        return None
        
    
    
    def insert_text(file_id):
        requests = [
            {
                'insertText': {
                    'location': {
                        'index': 1,
                    },
                    'text': 'Hellow'
                }
            },
            {
                'insertText': {
                    'location': {
                        'index': 7,
                    },
                    'text': 'Test'
                }
            },
    
        ]
    
        result = docs.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=file_id, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
        print(result)
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        folder_id = fetch_folder_id()
        file_id = create_Doc(folder_id)
        grant_permissions(file_id)
        insert_text(file_id)
```

Approach:

1. Fetch the `folder_id` where the doc file would be saved using the Drive API
2. Create the document inside that folder by making parent as `folder_id` using the Drive API
3. Grant required permissions to the document using the Drive API
4. Insert data inside the document using the Google Docs API

Error:
The file is getting created, and the permission is also granted but unable to insert data in the file.

```
    Found file: Document_API (1xUFjYPQiDxtqdhAScUKxYdbV_gwEdAWS)
    File ID: 1zasxzdaIc241raP7Ei41MRoqpg-f2sr3
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1483, in _exec
        pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
        exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
      File "C:/Users/xyz/Test/createdoc.py", line 118, in <module>
        insert_text(file_id)
      File "C:/Users/xyz/Test/createdoc.py", line 110, in insert_text
        result = docs.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=file_id, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
      File "C:\Users\ashutosh.f.tripathi\.virtualenvs\Testpython\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 131, in positional_wrapper
        return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ashutosh.f.tripathi\.virtualenvs\Testpython\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 937, in execute
        raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
    googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/1zasxzdaIc241raP7Ei41MRoqpg-f2sr3:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "This operation is not supported for this document". Details: "This operation is not supported for this document">
    python-BaseException
```

Comment: You are not creating a google doc here. You are just adding a file to drive folder. That might not work with document APIs

Answer (score 0):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
file_metadata = {
    'name': 'Test.docx',
    'parents': [folder_id]
}
```

#### To:

```
file_metadata = {
    'name': 'Test', # or if you want to give the filename of 'Test.docx', please set it.
    'parents': [folder_id],
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
}
```

- From the error message of `This operation is not supported for this document`, in this modification, `file_metadata` in the function `create_Doc` is modified. By this modification, Google Document is created and this Document can be used with Docs API.

  - In your current script, from the extention of `docx`, the created file has the mimeType of `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`. This is the reason of your issue.

Comment: @Ask_Ashu Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.